# How do I automatically convert data from string to number in typescript and angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I automatically convert data from string to number?

My data is not clear what it is and I want it to be automatically converted according to the type it has

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="formUser">
  <label>name: </label>
  <input formControlName="name" >
  <br>
  <label>name: </label>
  <input formControlName="userId" >
</form>
<button (click)="send()">send</button>
```

ts:

```
    export class AppComponent  {
      constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
    
      }
      formUser=this.fb.group({
        name:null,
        userId:null,
      })
       send(){
    const user:IUser=this.formUser.value
    console.log(user);
  }
}
interface IUser{
  name:string,
  userId:number
}
```

console:

```
{name: "alis", userId: "12"}
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I do not want to use the following method:

```
user.userId=Number(user.userId)
```

Comment: parseInt(number, 10) ?

Comment: Do you mean on change? Or when the Component is built? Or formatting the Value/Input?

Comment: `Angular cli : 11.1.4`, `node 14.17.0` , `Angular 11.1.2 `, `typescript:4.1.5`

Comment: I just gave an example otherwise my data can be anything and I do not want to change all the data manually

Comment: You can specify a `type` attribute in your input which is being respected...

Answer (score 1):

If the userId is always number you can use

```
<input formControlName="userId" type="number" />
```

So by default it will be of type number only.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to convert `string` values to `number` is by using the unary plus operator `+`:

```
user.userId = +user.userId;
```

More reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, he wants it to be converted automatically, not manually using `"+"` or `"Number(..)"`